# Customizing Firebase Authentication password reset template theme color

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I would like to change the theme color of Firebase Authentication custom email template for Password Reset. Currently, for no reason the button color and the highlight color of text field are dark blue. I would like it to be the same as the primary color of my app.

I can see that the template content can be edited but is it possible to style at least the color so that gives more branded look?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [how to customize the email action handler?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)

Comment: I see that this can be done by customizing the email action handler. However, it could be more UX friendly, less hassle and great enhancement to be able to just change the primary color of the default action handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [how to customize the email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). There is no specific setting to change just the primary color, but if you think that'd be a useful feature to add, I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).